# JCarousel adding extra space if I set custom start: position

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, foreach, jcarousel

I have a JQuery JCarousel set up in a CAKEPHP view. This particular view has a foreach loop to gather a series of thumbnails and titles from the database. If you click a page it returns another page with an enlargment and description of the piece clicked.

So, I am reloading the JCarousel on the second page with a start position of the item clicked on the previous page. I send the clicked id to the Query string "?n=id#" and I retrieve it using javascript, assign it to a variable and then to my JCarousel function. This works great, but the problem is that when I do this, the JCarousel adds blank space before the first item of the Carousel. Also ideally I would like to have the clicked Carousel item in the exact position as on the previous page. My entire carousel block is 8 per page and varies in size. So if I click the next button and then item 10, i'd like to start with the appearance of a next button click and show item 10 in the second spot. I've also played with offset and some math but nothing works. I hope this makes sense as it's driving me mad. :)

Here's my code:

**PHP page**

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">   
<?php $i=1; $cnt=1; ?>
<?php foreach($all_works as $work): ?>
<li class="clicked" id="<?php echo $cnt++; ?>">     
<a href="../../<?php echo $work['Work']['id'].DS.$work['Work']['category_id'].DS.$work['Work']['artist_id']; ?>?n=<?php echo $i++; ?>">
<?php echo $html->image('$image'.urlencode($work['Work']['picture']), array('border' => '0')); ?><span><?php echo $work['Work']['name']; ?></span></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul><span><?php echo $cnt; ?> pieces shown</span></div>
```

**Javascript to retrieve url and JCarousel:**

```
$.extend({ getUrlVars: function()
{var vars = [], hash; 
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{hash = hashes[i].split('=');
vars.push(hash[0]);
vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];}    
return vars;},  
getUrlVar: function(name)
{    
return $.getUrlVars()[name];  }});

var byName = $.getUrlVar('n');

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ 
scroll: 8,
start: byName
});
});
```

sorry about the formatting, first time posting to the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

So I show 8 items on my carousel at a time. If you show more or less than these number will need to be adjusted for your needs. I basically took the number of of the index I pass through the url string, divided it by 8.0001 (the .0001 part is so it isn't even on the multiples of 8) then I rounded it down. I did this because I need the start index to be the first visible item in the index,not necessarily the item that was clicked. I then multiplied it by 8. This gave me the solid multiples of 8, 16, 24 etc. I then added 8. This gave me my range for the else if statement. I then added one to the multiple of 8. This gave me my start position.

```
 $.extend(
         {  getUrlVars: function()
         {

                                 var vars = [], hash;    
                                 var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');    
                                 for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)    
                                 {      
                                 hash = hashes[i].split('=');      
                                 vars.push(hash[0]);      
                                 vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];    
                                 }    
                                 return vars;  
                                 },  
                                 getUrlVar: function(name)
                                 {    
                                 return $.getUrlVars()[name];  }});

var byName = $.getUrlVar('n');
var totalItems = $.getUrlVar('c');
var wrapType = "";
var offsetNumber ="";
var divisor = byName / 8.0001;
var mathRound = Math.floor(divisor);
var eightA = mathRound * 8;
var eightB = eightA + 8;
var eightC = eightA + 1;

if ( byName == null || byName <= 8 )
{
byName = 1;
wrapType = "";
offsetNumber = "0";
}
else if ( byName > eightA && byName <= eightB )
{
byName = eightC;
}
else
{
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ 
    scroll: 8,
    visible: 8,
    start: byName
 });
});
```